# Get some particular CSS elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let me explain.
I have a css page that is stored in a table, it presents itself in this form:

```
. styleFloatCenter, form.styleFloatCenter,. focus {
   margin: auto;
   width: 70%;
}
```

All css is built like that, it is a norm.
I need to recover for all my css "rules" the 2nd element like styleFloatCenter for my example.

An idea? Ty !

Edit :
2nd example :

```
. red, form.redColor,. focus {
   margin: auto;
   width: 70%;
}
```

Here i need redColor...

Comment: Still don't get what you want. Please clarify.

Comment: I need to recover, for each "rules" on my css page, the 2nd element. I nmy example i need to recover styleFloatCenter

Comment: If it comes from DB and your script transforms it into CSS, then why not let that same script give you "the second element" ?

Comment: Can you not do that server-side? Why do you want to use javascript?

Comment: I don't know, i can use javascirpt or php, i just want idea or suggest.

Comment: For each CSS rule, you want the class name of the second selector in the list of applicable selectors.  Correct?  What if the second selector has more than one class name, like `form.fooClass.barClass`?

Comment: No, it's a norm. 2nd element is always like "element.name". I need name for each rules on my CSS ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try javascript regex -

```
var pattern = /,(.+),/;
var oneRule = ". styleFloatCenter, form.styleFloatCenter,. focus {\
 margin: auto;\
 width: 70%;\
 }"; //store one rule in it
var result = pattern.exec(oneRule);
alert(result[1]); //Your required value​
```

Can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/63a8P/).
You can assign each rule one by one using loops.
If you want to parse the whole css doc together then first use a pattern to search a rule and then second element

Comment: Whats the problem now! If you want to do it in php you can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

To read your stylesheet rules, use `document.styleSheets`.  The following code lists the class names of the second selectors from all rules in all stylesheets on your page:

```
// for all stylesheets on the page
for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules || document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;

    // for all rules in this sheet
    for(var j = 0; j < rules.length; ++j) {

        // get the full selector string for this rule
        var selector = rules[j].selectorText;

        // get the second selector in the list
        var secondSelector = selector ? selector.split(",")[1] : null;

        // get the class name of that selector
        var secondSelectorClass = secondSelector ? secondSelector.split(".")[1] : null;

        console.log(secondSelectorClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("styleFloatCenter")[0])
```

If you have an element on the page with that class, you can get its [`computedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) using the code above. From there you can find any specific style you may be looking for.

By the way, you can't have a space between the dot and the selector name. `. styleFloatCenter` won't select elements with the class `styleFloatCenter`. It must be `.styleFloatCenter` without the space.

If you're just wanting the name of the second selector out of `.styleFloatCenter, form.styleFloatCenter,.focus`, you can simply use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the list at the commas and select the second one.

```
$parts = explode(',', '.styleFloatCenter, form.styleFloatCenter,.focus');
echo $parts[1];
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants *class names* that each rule in the stylesheet apply to, not style properties of objects with a particular class.